# Integration react-native-kit-ffmpeg and react-native-vision-camera in React Native

Tags: react-native, npm, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

"dependencies": {
"ffmpeg-kit-react-native": "^5.1.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.6",
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.4"
}

I am integration ffmpeg-kit-react-native and react-native-vision-camera in a react native project but facing this error

> The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher.
> The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
> project ':react-native-vision-camera' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30

Is there any issue in using these both packages?

Comment: Last RN version I'm sure vision camera is working is 0.71.4. At one point I've upgraded RN to 0.72 and then vision camera didn't work. So now I'm waiting for vision camera V3 to upgrade a project

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try upgrading react-native to version 0.71.8, then open the build.gradle file in the android directory of the project, and add the line kotlinVersion = "1.7.0" under buildscript ext. Install the project dependencies, and then restart the project